# FPS player Look.At() object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a Horror game.

I have a player, and an object (ghost).

My goal is to: after the player went into the dead end of the tunnel, he turns around and sees a ghost close up.

My approach: when the player reached the end he activates a trigger, a ghost 
appears behind him.

He turns around, a second trigger **makes the player (camera) focus onto the ghost object and locked dead on.** (focus on the ghost but player still able to move just the view will orbiting the ghost.

I tried with `transform.lookAt`. However, it does work the other way around (to make the object stare at the player), but it failed the other way.

Comment: Can you post a small snapshot of the code you tried? It helps us pinpoint the problem. :)

Comment: We can't help much without code xP

Comment: public class LookAt : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;

    void Update()
    {
        
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}

Comment: I figured out a way which is to turn firstpersoncontroller off, because the mouse is tied. however, the result is terriable....  i need a better approach please

Comment: Put your LookAt component on the Player and reference the object, then.

Comment: same, i tried many ways, including put it on my player, or player camera(eye). Neither works. is there a better way?

Comment: You either: Don't have lookat on the camera, are missing an object reference, or your code is clashing with code from another script you are running. It sounds like your lookat is clashing with your first person controller. If you are getting shaky cam that would be one sign that it is happening.